# An expression could also be a literal?

Tags: java, terminology

I was looking over my notes and it had the integer 5 as an expression when evaluated yields 5.

Definition of expression in my notes:

> Expression is java code that when evaluated yields a value

However I saw the definition of a literal:

> A Literal is the source code representation of a fixed value; literals are represented directly in your code without requiring computation

So wouldn't the integer 5 also be classified as a literal?
Is something wrong here or is it possible that an expression can also be a literal?

Comment: `5` is an `int` literal, yes.

Answer (score 3):

```
int i;
i = 5
```

is an expression which leads to a value of `5` for `i`, whilst `5` is a literal which leads to the integer number `5` as a result.

Answer (score 3):

5 is in deed a literal and a literal is a special case of an expression.

From the [Java Specification Section 15.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.2):

> Expressions can be broadly categorized into one of the following
>   syntactic forms:
>
> ```
> [...]
>
> Primary expressions (§15.8 - §15.13)
>
> [...]
> ```

And in [Section 15.8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.8): Literals are listed as one form of Primary Expression.

Comment: Thanks for providing JLS links.

Answer (score 1):

An int literal is an expression. And more generally a literal is an expression.

To get convinced of that you can have a glimpse to jdk source code that parses the language (in langtools) :

```
package com.sun.source.tree;    
public interface LiteralTree extends ExpressionTree {...
```